# In linux driver, why does kfree not work, when data pointer is passed in the function?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I try to make a simple program. 
the source code is below.
I try to kmalloc some memory, when inserts module. Then free memory, when remove module.
But I use command free and found that it does not free memory when remove module.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

#define FILE_NAME       "test"

typedef struct info
{
    char data[1048576];
}sInfo;

static sInfo* Info;

int mmap_alloc2(void* buf, int require_buf_size)
{
    struct page *page;
    void* mmap_buf;

    unsigned long mmap_size = PAGE_ALIGN(require_buf_size);
    printk("size=%lu\n",mmap_size);
    buf = kzalloc(mmap_size, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buf) {
        return -1;
    }
    mmap_buf = buf;
    for (page = virt_to_page(mmap_buf); page < virt_to_page(mmap_buf + mmap_size); page++) {
        SetPageReserved(page);
    }

    return 0;
}

void mmap_free2(void* buf, int require_buf_size)
{
    struct page *page;
    void *mmap_buf = buf;

    unsigned long mmap_size = PAGE_ALIGN(require_buf_size);
    printk("size=%lu\n",mmap_size);
    for (page = virt_to_page(mmap_buf); page < virt_to_page(mmap_buf + mmap_size); page++) {
        ClearPageReserved(page);
    }
    kfree((sInfo*)buf);
    mmap_buf = NULL;
}

static int mmap_example_init(void)
{
    struct proc_dir_entry *pEntry = NULL;
    printk("mmap example init\n");

    if(!(pEntry = create_proc_entry(FILE_NAME, 0666, NULL)))
    {
        printk("create proc entry fail\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    mmap_alloc2(Info, sizeof(sInfo));
    return 0;
}

static void mmap_example_exit(void)
{
    printk("mmap example exit\n");
    mmap_free2(Info, sizeof(sInfo));
    remove_proc_entry(FILE_NAME,NULL);
}

module_init(mmap_example_init);
module_exit(mmap_example_exit);
```

But when I change data pointer from function to global scope, kfree works.
code is below.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>


#define FILE_NAME       "test"

static void* mmap_buf;
typedef struct info
{
    char data[1048576];
}sInfo;

static sInfo* Info;

int mmap_alloc1(int require_buf_size)
{
    struct page *page;

    int mmap_size = PAGE_ALIGN(require_buf_size);
    mmap_buf = kzalloc(mmap_size, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!mmap_buf) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (page = virt_to_page(mmap_buf ); page < virt_to_page(mmap_buf + mmap_size); page++) {
        SetPageReserved(page);
    }

    return 0;
}

void mmap_free1(int require_buf_size)
{
    struct page *page;
    unsigned long mmap_size = PAGE_ALIGN(require_buf_size);
    for (page = virt_to_page(mmap_buf); page < virt_to_page(mmap_buf + mmap_size); page++) {
        ClearPageReserved(page);
    }
    kfree(mmap_buf);
    mmap_buf = NULL;
}


static int mmap_example_init(void)
{
    struct proc_dir_entry *pEntry = NULL;
    printk("mmap example init\n");

    if(!(pEntry = create_proc_entry(FILE_NAME, 0666, NULL)))
    {
        printk("create proc entry fail\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    mmap_alloc1(sizeof(sInfo));
    return 0;
}

static void mmap_example_exit(void)
{
    printk("mmap example exit\n");
    mmap_free1(sizeof(sInfo));
    remove_proc_entry(FILE_NAME,NULL);
}

module_init(mmap_example_init);
module_exit(mmap_example_exit);
```

so what is the difference in this two code? and how to modify sample1 to make kfree work?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code sample, you are allocating the memory, but you are not really assigning the address to pointer variable Info. And your mmap_buf is a local variable which doesn't really do anything in the first case. So you are trying to free some random address. Which may or may not work. Usually it doesn't and definitely not what you are trying to free.

You can either make mmap_alloc2() return the pointer and assign it to Info, like `Info = mmap_alloc2(sizeof(sInfo));` or pass the address of Info to the function, like,`int mmap_alloc2(void **buf, int require_buf_size)` and `*buf = kzalloc(mmap_size, GFP_KERNEL);`. Call it with `mmap_alloc2(&Info, sizeof(sInfo));`